# Cómo distinguir en android si se ejecuta mi app en un emulador u otro dispositivo

Tags: android, android-studio, desarrollo

espero puedan ayudarme con esto: tengo una app de android desarrollada en java la cual se conecta a una url x, necesito hacer unas pruebas en el emulador de android studio pero conectándome a mi servidor de desarrollo con otra url y no se cómo decirle en código que cuando esté en el emulador se conecte a una url y cuando sea otro dispositivo a otra. Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Creo que es imposible a menos que le pidas al usuario que te lo diga y tenga la gentileza de responderte sinceramente. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21505193/13419694

Comment: Mateo Me ayudo la liga que puso y usando Build.PRODUCT.conatains("sdk") funciona por ahora. Gracias

Comment: si es en android studio podes definir un perfil o configuracion de ejecución https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig?hl=es-419#opening un par de launch flags te evitan tener la/s url/s de desarrollo dentro de la app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con ese código de Kotlin, lo he probado con dispositivos reales y todos me han devuelvto `false` , no tengo emulador instalado

```kotlin
private fun isEmulator(): Boolean {
    return (Build.BRAND.startsWith("generic") && Build.DEVICE.startsWith("generic")
            || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("generic")
            || Build.FINGERPRINT.startsWith("unknown")
            || Build.HARDWARE.contains("goldfish")
            || Build.HARDWARE.contains("ranchu")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("google_sdk")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Emulator")
            || Build.MODEL.contains("Android SDK built for x86")
            || Build.MANUFACTURER.contains("Genymotion")
            || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk_google")
            || Build.PRODUCT.contains("google_sdk")
            || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk")
            || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk_x86")
            || Build.PRODUCT.contains("sdk_gphone64_arm64")
            || Build.PRODUCT.contains("vbox86p")
            || Build.PRODUCT.contains("emulator")
            || Build.PRODUCT.contains("simulator"))
}
```

su uso

```kotlin
Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "corre en emulador?: " + isEmulator(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo que me ocurre en este momento, es que puedas a través de un `EditText` colocar alguna especie de número y dentro de un `if-else` verifiques el número ingresado. Por ejemplo, en el celular físico puedes escribir un 1 y que cuando sea 1 lo mandas a cierta `URL`, si metes un 2, esto lo estarás haciendo desde el emulador y ejecutas la otra `URL`. Creo que esa sería la forma más simple y rápida de hacerlo.